# Debug PHP in Real Time

Tags: php, debugging

I have an open source web application that has many files, which is why I want to debug it in real time:

**While I am surfing the web application, I want it to show me the physical path on localhost for the URL requested as well as all the files that are used to render this specific page.**

Is there any tool for this?

[image: Image of some HTML in the Chrome developer toolbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Xdebug function traces feature](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace).

Since you already use Xdebug, you just have to add some configuration in your `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.auto_trace=On    # Start tracing before the script is run
xdebug.collect_params=4 # Show full variable contents and variable name
```

The trace file will, by default, be written to `/tmp`. On Windows you better set that yourself with `xdebug.trace_output_dir=C:\somedir`

[PHP has also something built-in](http://php.net/debug_backtrace), but its not as nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xDebug with PHPStorm and Google Chrome plugin as described on [JetBrains wiki page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Configure+Xdebug+Helper+for+Chrome+to+be+used+with+PhpStorm)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [phptrace](https://github.com/Qihoo360/phptrace).

> phptrace is a low-overhead tracing tool for PHP.
>
> It can trace all PHP executing, function calls, request information during run-time. And provides features like Filter, Statistics, Current Status and so on.
>
> It is very useful to locate blocking, heavy-load problems and debug in all environments, especially in production environments.
>
> Features:
>
> - low-overhead, when extension loaded and trace is off
>   stable,
> - running on Qihoo 360 and tested on main-stream frameworks